# Link error when subclassing string

Tags: c++, googletest, subclassing

for various reasons I subclassed the std::string like:

```
   class CotengString : public string
         {
        public:
        // Constructors
        CotengString();
        CotengString(const char* ch) : string(ch) {}
        CotengString(const string& str) : string(str) {}
        virtual ~CotengString() {};

        //Operator"="
        CotengString& operator=(const string& str) { return (CotengString&)this->assign(str); }
        CotengString& operator=(const char* ch) { return (CotengString&)this->assign(ch); }
    };
```

Inside the DLL I wish to use this code all compiles correctly. But inside my Google Test project I get this error after switching to the subclassed string

```
LNK2005 "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *,unsigned int)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBDI@Z) already defined in gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)    Devices.Spectro.CppTest <path>\Devices.Spectro.CppTest\Devices.Spectro.Cpp.lib(Devices.Spectro.Cpp.dll)
```

My gut feeling is that I am missing something obvious. But I don't know what it could be

Comment: Do you seriously need to derive from std::string here?

Comment: Maybe this code is only shortend for example purpose

Comment: Generally speaking you should never inherit from standard containers...

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is no worse than inheriting from anything else, but gratuitous inheritance can be a red flag. The boilerplate shown here is also a bit smelly. Likely `using string::string; using string::operator =;` would do a better job than reimplementing things manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, then as answer.

#### First cause

This seems to me to be a problem of multiple includes of header files.
This results in that the compiler wants to compile functions or in this case allocators again and detects "oh I already compiled that!".

So fix would be to add to the header file this:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION_HEADER
#define CUSTOM_STRING_IMPLEMENTATION_HEADER

....

#endif
```

#### Second cause

However, if this isn't the case maybe you're trying to compile this file again in your code which uses the dll which ***already contains the compiled class.***

*I personally think it's the second cause according to your log file. There's said that the allocator is already compiled in your library.*

#### Example:

If you're using only header files this results in a big problem. Look here.

Dll code:

SomeHeaderFile.hpp

```
class NiceClass{
//Constructor is implemented. That causes several problems now! 
NiceClass{

 }
...
}
```

Your application code (wich uses the dll):

SomeNiceApplicationCode:

```
//Linker error now! It's already compiled right into your dll!
#include <SomeHeaderFile.hpp>

int main(){
   NiceClass niceClassInstance;
   return 0;
}
```

## Solution:

Apply those changes and create and extra cpp file for your class.

Include in your application file ***only the header file***.

```
class CotengString : public string
     {
    public:
    // Constructors
    CotengString();
    CotengString(const char* ch) : string(ch); //Use cpp file!
    CotengString(const string& str) : string(str); //""
    virtual ~CotengString(); //""

    //Operator"="
    CotengString& operator=(const string& str); //Same for this
    CotengString& operator=(const char* ch); //""
};
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: The second cause means, that you have to find where you're possible compiling the same class again. Could you post more code ?

Comment: The solution should solve your problem. Damit that I did not see that instantly D:

Comment: Thank you, I was already implementing this along those lines ;)

Comment: So problem solved? If so please do not forget to accept the answer ;D

Comment: It solved some of the link errors (I got 18, now I got 15 of those) but I guess I have to add more overloaded constructors